# I want to write a rmlmapper and apply it to a variable not a file . Is it possible (rmlapper-java)?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, rdfs, turtle-rdf, rml-rdf

I want to write a java code (like the code in be.ugent.rml.readme>ReadmeTest.java) to take a json data in a variable and use the mapping.ttl file to map and convert to rdf .
As of now the mapping.ttl file has the file name in it .
I want to replace that file name with a variable containing json data .
Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: that's not possible unless you extend the Java code by yourself. The obvious question, why can't you put the JSON data into a file?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you have to change the LocalFileAccess.java file in the rmlmapper.jar .
Learn the java files in rmlmapper-java repository .